# How can I distinguish between youtube-dl getting a ctrl-c and getting some other error in a shell script?

Tags: bash, scripting, exit-code, youtube-dl

I have a set of scripts for archiving youtube channels that consists of:

1. an awk script that reads a list of channels and archiving parameters and uses `system()` to run...
2. ...a bash script that takes those arguments and invokes `youtube-dl` (and does some other things)

I've modified the awk script to exit when it gets a non-zero return code from the bash script, because I want to be able to kill the whole process while youtube-dl is downloading (if I don't do this, it would just move on to the next channel).

However, I've found that youtube-dl will give the same nonzero return code when it gets a ctrl-c or when it encounters some other error.  This is causing my script to exit early, because some of the channels I'm archiving have private videos that youtube-dl skips, which seems to count as an error.

**How can I have my bash script distinguish between youtube-dl getting killed with a ctrl-c and it getting some other error?**

**Examples**

`youtube-dl` version:

```
(youtube-dl-venv)$ youtube-dl --version
2021.03.03
```

`youtube-dl` exiting with 1 when killed with Ctrl-C:

```
(youtube-dl-venv)$ youtube-dl --force-ipv4 --sleep-interval 15 --ignore-errors --no-continue --no-overwrites -r 1M https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcHpteNEx4B221FIkGOlhnQ
[youtube:tab] UCcHpteNEx4B221FIkGOlhnQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Kaypro Due - Home
[youtube:tab] playlist Kaypro Due - Home: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube:tab] UCcHpteNEx4B221FIkGOlhnQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Kaypro Due - Videos
[youtube:tab] playlist Kaypro Due - Videos: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] X2nrfbXdfRU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] X2nrfbXdfRU: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Sleeping 15 seconds...
^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
(youtube-dl-venv)$ echo $?
1
```

`youtube-dl` exiting with 1 when encountering a private video:

```
(youtube-dl-venv)$ youtube-dl --force-ipv4 --sleep-interval 15 --ignore-errors --no-continue --no-overwrites -r 1M https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfu3xDF_96dO_ce4vEzhzAkZ-H1glnOjf
[youtube:tab] PLfu3xDF_96dO_ce4vEzhzAkZ-H1glnOjf: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Test Playlist
[youtube:tab] playlist Test Playlist: Downloading 2 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 2
[youtube] 6JlpzbgouUE: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Private video
Sign in if you've been granted access to this video
[download] Downloading video 2 of 2
[youtube] oN0G-ebwmZ8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] oN0G-ebwmZ8: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Test Video 2-oN0G-ebwmZ8.mp4 has already been downloaded and merged
[download] Finished downloading playlist: Test Playlist
(youtube-dl-venv)$ echo $?
1
```

`youtube-dl` exiting with 0 when successfully downloading a channel:

```
(youtube-dl-venv)$ youtube-dl --force-ipv4 --sleep-interval 15 --ignore-errors --no-continue --no-overwrites -r 1M https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcHpteNEx4B221FIkGOlhnQ
[youtube:tab] UCcHpteNEx4B221FIkGOlhnQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Kaypro Due - Home
[youtube:tab] playlist Kaypro Due - Home: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube:tab] UCcHpteNEx4B221FIkGOlhnQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Kaypro Due - Videos
[youtube:tab] playlist Kaypro Due - Videos: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] X2nrfbXdfRU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] X2nrfbXdfRU: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Sleeping 15 seconds...
[download] Destination: Panasonic Whisper Series Bath Fan Slow Startup-X2nrfbXdfRU.f136.mp4
[download] 100% of 32.61MiB in 00:33
[download] Sleeping 15 seconds...
[download] Destination: Panasonic Whisper Series Bath Fan Slow Startup-X2nrfbXdfRU.f140.m4a
[download] 100% of 1.40MiB in 00:01
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "Panasonic Whisper Series Bath Fan Slow Startup-X2nrfbXdfRU.mp4"
Deleting original file Panasonic Whisper Series Bath Fan Slow Startup-X2nrfbXdfRU.f136.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file Panasonic Whisper Series Bath Fan Slow Startup-X2nrfbXdfRU.f140.m4a (pass -k to keep)
[download] Finished downloading playlist: Kaypro Due - Videos
[download] Finished downloading playlist: Kaypro Due - Home
(youtube-dl-venv)$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Would the trick I used [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/42021/how-to-ping-in-linux-until-host-is-known/42382#42382) work? That is, have the script run `youtube-dl` in the background, trap SIGINT and have the trap both kill `youtube-dl` *and* note that it was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output to some temporary file and check for `Interrupted by user` string in that file:

```
$ youtube-dl ... 2> >(tee /tmp/sometempfile.txt >&2)
....
^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
$ grep 'ERROR: Interrupted by user' /tmp/sometempfile.txt
```